# Two question about how to compute this integral limit

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f: (-\pi,\pi]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous and let  $p_x (u) = {(f(u+x) - f(x)) \cos ({u \over 2}) \over \sin ({u \over 2}) }$. I want to show that 
$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi p_x(u) \sin (Nu) du \to 0$$

as $N \to \infty$. I had two ideas but I don't know if they work. Can you please tell me if the ideas are correct?

Note that the only point where $p_x$ may not be continuous is $u = 0$.

Idea 1: Since $\int_{[a,b]} = \int_{(a,b]}$ and $\int_a^b = \int_a^c + \int_c^b$ for all $c \in (a,b)$:

$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi p_x(u) \sin (Nu) du = \int_{-\pi}^0 p_x(u) \sin (Nu) du + \int_0^\pi p_x(u) \sin (Nu) du$$

By the Riemann Lebesgue lemma both integrals on the right tend to $0$ hence there sum does also tend to $0$.

Idea 2: Alsmost the same as idea but if using $\int_{[a,b]} = \int_{(a,b]}$ does not work then let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then

$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi p_x(u) \sin (Nu) du = \int_{-\pi}^{-\varepsilon} p_x(u) \sin (Nu) du + \int_\varepsilon^\pi p_x(u) \sin (Nu) du$$

and by Riemann Lebesgue lemma both integrals on the right tend to $0$ as $N \to \infty$. Since $\varepsilon $ was arbitrary, let $\varepsilon \to 0$. Then the claim follows?

Comment: I think that $f$ should have a  right derivative at $x$